# Center div both horizontally and vertically using absolute position

Tags: css

I followed some guides to make a div to center both vertically and horizontally, but it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ony80a5d/

```
<div class="c">center</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.c {
    background: grey;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: use `margin: auto;` it will work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ony80a5d/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to add `margin: auto` to the element. In modern browsers, this will center the element horizontally/vertically.

For more approaches on centering an element horizontally/vertically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/06kuxLum/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.c {
    background: grey;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="c">center</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set your element to be of width 50%, but you haven't set any positioning other then zero values for top/left etc. set your top and left to 50% and transform the position, like this:

```
.c {
    background: grey;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set margins anywhere in your code. Just put this `margin:auto` in your **.c** class . For Example http://jsfiddle.net/ony80a5d/4/

Answer (score 0):

if your width and height are 50%, why don't you use

```
left:25%;
top: 25%;
```